# Unable to Play Game of Online Invite with PS5 and Mortal Kombat X

Tags: playstation-plus, mortal-kombat-x, ps5

I have Mortal Kombat X on my PS5 which I downloaded from the PS Plus store. A friend of mine has the disc version of the same game. We went to Online -> Private match and tried sending invites to each other. When we go to the received invite, it takes us to "Play Game". When I click on it, it brings me back to the main menu and doesn't take to the game.

We both have PS5 Disc and Mortal Kombat X. He's using the game in disc and I'm using downloaded version. We're also both in CA region.

What is causing us to not be able to play this online game? Would appreciate any advice.

Another observation is that, we both see the same room names when we go to "Rooms" in the game. But when he creates one, I'm not seeing that.

Comment: Does your friend have a PS+ subscription?

Comment: Yes he has! But this game for him wasn't downloaded in PS+ because he uses a disc